# Save every 20 secs. Causing 1004 error

Tags: vba, excel, save, runtime-error

I have an excel doc on a shared drive that saves the active workbook every 20 sec.

```
Sub Save()
   ActiveWorkbook.Save
   Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:20"), "Save"
End Sub
```

It works fine when one or two users on using it. However, if three or more users are using it then it starts to throw

> runtime error 1004 the file is locked

I believe this is happening because the document is already in the middle of being saved by another user. Is there a way around this error? For example is there a way to see if another user is saving to a shared work book with VBA?

Or is there a way to trigger a save event if another user has made changes to the document? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Consider leveraging Excel's built-in autosave/autorecover feature instead. Also over a slow network and depending on file size, 20 seconds might not be enough to get any actual work done between saves. I'd comment-out that macro without blinking.

Comment: Does it hang if the user is modifying a cell?  Another question was trying to close on a timer but was over ridden if the user was using the sheet.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/48121305/8716187

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can right-click on the worksheet tab, and choose "View Code". In this window you should be able to type the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ActiveWorkbook.save
End Sub
```

There's also code for checking if it's locked, so if you want to combine the above with a timer (in the case it's locked), then you could do something like...

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
       Save(Target)
   End Sub

   Sub Save(ByVal Target As Range)
       ' check shared and stop sharing
       With ActiveWorkbook
       If .MultiUserEditing Then
           Application.DisplayAlerts = False
           .ExclusiveAccess
           Application.DisplayAlerts = True
       End If
       End With
       'resave with sharing switched on
       With ActiveWorkbook
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .SaveAs Filename:=.FullName, AccessMode:=xlShared
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
       End With
   End Sub
```

Edit: MoondogsMaDawg makes a good point. I've updated the code to choose a random value between 1-10 seconds (feel free to change as needed).

Edit #2: Found a better solution for obtaining exclusive access and saving it, so it shouldn't ever have to check if it's locked.

**Note: I do not create Excel macros often so please excuse my mistakes.**

Source: [MrExcel run-time-error](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/653786-run-time-error-1004-shared-workbook-macro.html)

Comment: If two users open the same file in sync with the 20 second delay, it will collide on every call thereafter and neither will be saved until one of them closes the workbook. Try adding a random number (from 1-10, say) to the TimeValue, so that you can offset the two colliding users.

Comment: `If Target.Locked = False Then` is checking if the Range is locked, not the workbook. Maybe I don't understand that if the workbook is locked the range is too, but just wanted to point it out in case what I suspect is correct.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I believe this set me on the right path. One thing I'm not sure about though. Will worksheet_change pick up on changes made by another user or will it only see changes made by the local user?

Comment: I think we had a similar question recently where if a user was typing (change) at the time of the save or close would not work as excel was firing other handlers.

Comment: Cody, as long as everyone has macros enabled in Excel, the event will fire each time a user makes a chance (on their own Excel on their own computer). I also updated the solution to (hopefully) have a better solution to maintaining exclusive access and allowing to save in regards to Scott's concern above.